# Chai being ambiguous with failings on Arrays

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai

I'm running Chai unit testing. However, I'm testing a schema property, and getting this failing unit test:

```
Foo Schema functionality
  Bar
    should return data Array if appropriate values are passed
AssertionError: expected [ Array(2) ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
```

And this is with code that says

```
Baz = myFunction(data)
expect(Baz).to.have.same.members([null, {Foo:Bar, Bash:Baz}])
```

Is there a way to get it to actually print out the full arrays with objects so I can see if its my unit test screwing up or my code?

I *want* output that looks more like

```
Foo Schema functionality
  Bar
    should return data Array if appropriate values are passed
AssertionError: expected [null, {Foo:Barf, Bash:Baz}] to deeply equal [null, {Foo:Bar, Bash:Baz}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code example

Comment: That's all the applicable code to my knowledge, but I'm still fairly new to node and chai, and it's a fairly large code base. Is there a chai setting that changes it?